# Why has my LVL licence test stopped working?

Tags: android, android-lvl

I created a licence test app a year ago that was identical to the sample licence test, added the key and uploaded as draft. It worked exactly as it should. Now when I run the exact same app I get an application error 3 message every time. I am using the exact same device and the exact same account so nothing at all has changed whatsoever, so why is it now not working? I have a new app ready for market but I need to resolve this problem so I can test the LVL on the new app (which has the same application error response problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditions of the LVL has just changed. Now, You have to give Your app a Beta Test status to get it work. On the developer console, select Your app, select APK, and then put it into the Beta Status. It needs a time to change, 24 hours is not unusual.